# Pass the value to nth variable in a function without passing values's to n-1 th variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass value to second parameter only .

```
function ask(x, y){
  alert(x+":"+y);
}

ask(y=9);
```

alert should be --> undefined:9

Is there any way to do so .

Request you not to tell that is should do below thing

```
ask(undefined,9);
```

Comment: So where's the 3rd parameter?

Comment: Sorry i just updated the question

Comment: You don't. Create a wrapper, or play games in the function based on params values, or pass an object, apply partial function application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't support named parameters; you can't do that.  You can use destructuring to simulate it.

```
function ask({x, y}={}) {
  alert(x+":"+y);
}

ask({y: 1});
```

Comment: Assuming ES6, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function ask (x, y) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    // only one argument was given. Set it to 'y'.
    y = arguments[0];
    x = undefined;
  }
  alert(x+":"+y);
}
```

Some tests:

```
ask('hello', 'world'); // alerts 'hello:world'
ask('oops'); // alerts 'undefined:oops'
```

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption that is stated in the question.